# jQuery / Javascript: Show Image when link is clicked. Then when another link clicked, show different image, while hiding the previous visible image

Tags: image, show

I have 4 images and 4 links referencing each image.

Image 1 will appear by default. When users click on link 2, image 2 will replace image 1 and so on with link 3 & 4.

I've set the html as a list item like so:

```
<ul class="nav-tabs"> 

    <li>
        <img class="activeImg" src="img1.jpg" />
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
        <img src="img4.jpg" />
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>          

</ul>
```

Css:

```
.nav-tabs li img.activeImg{
    visibility: visible;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs li img:nth-child(1)').addClass("activeImg");
    $('.nav-tabs li img:nth-child(2)').hide();
});

$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(3)').click(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs li img:nth-child(2)').addClass("activeImg");
    $('.nav-tabs li img:nth-child(1)').hide();
});
```

This doesn't work well since it hides everything.

I need help as you can see. Please provide some working examples in either jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code from w3c which works well for my case and a lot more simpler than what my mind was conjuring up:

```
<img id="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm.gif";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JS only can do what you want(no css needed):

```
<ul class="nav-tabs"> 
    <li>
        <img src="http://cue.me/kohana/media/frontend/js/full-page-scroll/examples/imgs/bg3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage('http://cue.me/kohana/media/frontend/js/full-page-scroll/examples/imgs/bg3.jpg')">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage('http://cue.me/kohana/media/frontend/js/full-page-scroll/examples/imgs/bg2.jpg')">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQ7r5XGxggyodPsnaEkQ9SAWjx1-zx8NKDkBz0EXATC78u-gBd')">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeImage('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQpsAzFOuzE07HdIByvXNGeBeflF-9wRpdDHAYKfkQQQjS1AiOZ')">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    function changeImage(img_name){
      document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = img_name
    }
</script>
```

TRY IT HERE https://jsfiddle.net/hnb9Lko3/1/